# Use the values of a column (instead of numeric ids) as foreign key reference

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Was not sure how to express this in the title. So here's the deal: I have a table storing information about currency pairs used in foreign exchange rates:

```
PAIR_ID | BASE_CURRENCY | TERM_CURRENCY | ATTRIBUTE1 | ATTRIBUTE2 ...
```

Ideally I should have another table to store the currency symbols (master data), say `CURRENCY_SYMBOLS` and foreign keys from `BASE_CURRENCY` and `TERM_CURRENCY` to this table. However I am confused about 2 possible approaches here.

**Approach 1**:

**CURRENCY_PAIRS**:

```
PAIR_ID | BASE_CURRENCY_ID | TERM_CURRENCY_ID | ATTRIBUTE1 | ATTRIBUTE2 ...
```

**CURRENCY_SYMBOLS**:

```
SYMBOL_ID | SYMBOL
```

with `BASE_CURRENCY_ID` & `TERM_CURRENCY_ID` referencing `SYMBOL_ID`

Or **Approach 2**: rather than having a symbol_id that really adds no value, just have:

**CURRENCY_PAIRS**:

```
PAIR_ID | BASE_CURRENCY | TERM_CURRENCY | ATTRIBUTE1 | ATTRIBUTE2 ...
```

**CURRENCY_SYMBOLS**:

```
SYMBOL
```

with `BASE_CURRENCY` & `TERM_CURRENCY` referencing the `SYMBOL` directly.

I am not sure which one is better, approach 1 seems ideal but really no advantage - in fact in all my queries an additional join will be needed to retrieve data.

Approach 2 seems more efficient but somehow not correct.

Any pointers on which one I should go with?

Comment: What makes you believe that approach #2 is *somehow not correct*? A primary key must be unique and not null, and to be efficient in SQL Server (you didn't mention what actual database you're using) it also ideally is small and fixed length. Those currency codes are an ISO standard, they hardly ever change, they're exactly 3 characters long - sounds like an almost **ideal** primary key to me! Yes, I often use an `ID`, too - to make things easier, safer, more efficient. But a `CHAR(3)` for your ISO currency code is very close to perfect for a SQL Server primary key

Comment: I am on Oracle - well it was just a feeling that maybe it's not correct based on experience/in-experience :P

Comment: It's A Bad Idea. See my comment below.

Comment: How would you join the two tables in Approach 2, without the CURRENCY_ID in the CURRENCY_SYMBOLS table?

Comment: I think that the currencies should have their own table (CURRENCIES) with columns as CURRENCY_ID, SYMBOL, COUNTRY, etc. Both BASE_CURRENCY_ID and TERM_CURRENCY_ID in CURRENCY_PAIRS would be FK to the CURRENCIES.CURRENCY_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 2 seems like a good idea at first, but there are a few problems with it. I'll list them all even though 1 and 2 don't really apply as much to you, since you're only using it with 3-digit ISO codes:

1. **Foreign key references can take up more room.** Depending on how long you need to make your VARCHARs, they can take up more room as foreign keys then, say, a byte or a short. If you have zillions of objects which refer to these foreign keys then it adds up. Some DBs are smart about this and replace the VARCHARs with hash table references in the referring tables, but some don't. No DB is smart about it 100% of the time.
2. **You're necessarily exposing database keys (which should have no meaning, at least to end-users) as business keys.** What if the bosses want to replace "USD" with "$" or "Dollars"? You would need to add a lookup table in that case, negating a primary reason to use this approach in the first place. Otherwise you'd need to change the value in the CURRENCY_SYMBOLS, which can be tricky (See #3).
3. **It's hard to maintain.** Countries occasionally change. They change currencies as they enter/leave the Euro, have coups, etc. Sometimes just the name of the currency becomes politically incorrect. With this approach you not only would have to change the entry in CURRENCY_SYMBOLS, but cascade that change to every object in the DB that refers to it. That could be incredibly slow. Also, since you have no constant keys, the keys the programmers are hard-wiring into their business logic are these same keys that have now changed. Good luck hunting through the entire code base to find them all.

I often use a "hybrid" approach; that is, I use approach 1 but with a very short VARCHAR as the ID (3 or 4 characters max). That way, each entry can have a "SYMBOL" field which is exposed to end users and can be changed as needed by simply modifying the one table entry. Also, developers have a slightly more meaningful ID than trying to remember that "14" is the Yen and "27" is the US Dollar. Since these keys are not exposed, they don't have to change so long as the developers remember that `YEN` was the currency before The Great Revolution. If a query is just for business logic, you may still be able to get away with not using a join. It's slower for some things but it's faster for others. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you need a join so you are not saving a join.

Option 1 adds an ID. This ID will default to have a clustered index. Meaning the data is sorted on disk with the lowest ID first and the highest ID at the end. This is a flexible option that will allow easy future development.

Option 2 will hard code the symbols into the Currency Pairs table. This means if at a later date you want to add another column to the symbols table, eg for grouping, you will need to create the symbol_id field and update all your records in the currency pairs table. This increases maintenance costs.

I always add int ID fields for this sort of table because the overhead is low and maintenance is easier.

There are also indexing advantages to option 1

Comment: Not true! If there's no other information in CURRENCY_SYMBOLS then there's no point in doing a join; if you have the name you have all the information available. The presence of the CURRENCY_SYMBOLS table is strictly to enforce a limited set of values. This is not a good approach, though for a number of reasons.

Comment: Well in Approach 2 I need not join since I will get the currency symbol directly. Assuming there will be no columns added to symbol, would Approach 2 be better?

Comment: @AlvinThompson you are saying Approach 2 is a bad idea? - can you explain the "number of reasons"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the symbol id, but it is close.  This assumes that you really mean the currency abbreviation, rather than the symbol.  I generally prefer surrogate numeric keys.  If I have to use a string, then I want to avoid international characters.

One issue is dealing with currencies that may not be international standards or that may change over time.  In the past 15 years, we have seen many currencies change, primarily to the euro.  But you have other instances where, say, the Turkish lira was re-evaluated.  So if you used your own definition, you might not distinguish between the two currencies.

Also, depending on your application, you may be calling something a "currency" when it is not an official currency.  This happens when financial products are priced using some sort of basket of currencies (or other benchmark metric), but you want to treat "currency-basket bonds" the same way as other bonds in your system.

Because the issue of currencies is more complicated than I had once thought, I would lean to having a surrogate key to give the application more flexibility.